# How does this internally work to merge arrays using prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How does it work ? i gone through this [documentation](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-typical-javascript-interview-exercises/) but still not clear about its functionality according to me new array should get pushed at index no 4 and length should be 3 then how they are appended with length 6.

```
var a = [4,5,6];
var b = [7,8,9];
Array.prototype.push.apply(a, b);
```

can someone explain it in a better way because i have gone through several post but still not clear about it's working. 
[More Info](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/02/28/javascript-confusing-call-and-apply/)

Comment: `a` will be the value that is worked on (internally known as `this`) and `b` will be a list of arguments in the form of an array, so every element in one array gets pushed into the first array. `apply` is a way of executing the function and setting the this value to a certain pointer so it can act as if it is that thing.

Comment: note that if you want to concat two arrays you don't need this trick, you can use `a = a.concat(b)` which is clearer and possibly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.push.apply(a, b);

In this statement Array object's push method is invoked keeping Array 'a' the context and Array 'b' as the array of arguments for the function push of Array prototype.

So, this statement simply pushes the elements of Array 'b' into Array 'a'. And returns the length of the resultant array, which will be 6 in this case.

Try swapping the a with b and logging them.

For any doubt see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 0):

apply runs the function in context of first argument and another argument is list of parameters that will be passed to function. In your case it's similar to call 
`a.push(7,8,9)`